# CSS line-height doesn't affect Cufon fonts

Tags: css, fonts, cufon

I'm using Cufon ( https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/about ) to use special fonts in my website. But when I apply line-height in CSS, it doesn't affect my Cufon fonts. But in IE it does work. What could be reason for this behaviour?

Comment: You say it works in IE; does it fail in Firefox and Webkit-based browsers?

Comment: Yes, in Firefox and Safari it doesn't work at all...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The doctype needs to be strict for line-height to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for this. Not only did I learn how to fix my problem, I also taught myself the importance of DOCTYPE's too, which is ridiculously overdue! :)

Comment: If you can, avoid using line-height in elements or parent elements affected by Cufon. Sometimes you can simulate a line-height with padding and margin.